# Ubuntu experience on a Chromebook

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu, chrome-book

So I want to buy a cheap laptop, just to code and I need Ubuntu for that. So I thought about Chromebooks, but some questions came to my mind:

> **1.** *Which methods are available to install ubuntu on a chromebook?*
>
> **2.** *Is it just a virtual machine or a full installation?, therefore, is it able to use all hardware available?*
>
> **3.** *Is there any difference between normal ubuntu experience and chromebook's ubuntu experience? (anything).*
>
> **4.** *Is every Chromebook capable of installing and running well ubuntu?*
>
> **5.** Is it possible to run KDE or kubuntu?

Thanks in advance, and if you may, please name one good and lightweight chromebook you know.

Comment: AskUbuntu has [a chromebook tag](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/chromebook)... Oh, I see you have crossposted--don't do that.

Comment: I did it because I'm not sure where does this topic belong to.

Comment: Well, it is pretty clearly an Ubuntu-specific question.

Comment: Crouton is a good option

Comment: I advise you to get a strong machine if your serious about coding. You will certainly want a strong CPU and all the ram you can afford. You will also want an x86 processor and not ARM (unless your writing apps for ARM machines) cross compiling is not a good way to do the majority of your work.

Comment: what do you mean by 'serious'? I am going to use c++, qt, and maybe OpenGl some time in the future.

Comment: @coteyr Does ChromeOS run on ARM? I was not aware of that.

Comment: Yep chromebooks can certianly be ARM base, or X86 based.

Answer (score 1):

Look up *crouton*. With it you are able to download and install Ubuntu, as well as debian, and kali. For more (*a lot more*) information, go to [this website](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/install-ubuntu-on-your-chromebook-using.html). 
 Also, yes it is a full installation...